# AWS Cloudformation: Callback only for CREATE_COMPLETE or CREATE_FAILED of entire stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a CF stack;

I have been using the `--notification-arns` flag of `aws cloudformaction create-stack` to send notifications to an email topic; however this produces a huge amount of spam, given that it records **every** `X_IN_PROGRESS` **and** `X_COMPLETE`, where `X=CREATE/DELETE` for **every** resource on the stack;

I just want to get notifications for the **stack** `CREATE/DELETE` events.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, alternatively, you could use CloudTrail+CloudWatch rules, but then you will get CREATE_STACK events for *all* stacks
Here is some information about that:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-api-logging-cloudtrail.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html

And, of course, there's the option to put a lambda which listens on the notification topic and filters the needed events before sending the email.